# Q:How to search text on value and delite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want this code to be able to change using javascript or jquery amount in value remains 2.00 and not 2.00лв.
Please help I made many attempts but failed

```
<input value="2.00лв." id="price" name="price" size="1" style="height: 22px; width: 80px" type="text">
```

Comment: `I made many attempts but failed` Post them in question itself

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace method of JavaScript.

```
.replace("лв.","")
```

JS Fiddle Link:
https://jsfiddle.net/f1s41qez/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parseFloat()`-function:

```
var price = $('#price').val(); //get the value from the input
price = parseFloat(price); //convert the value to a float-number
$('#price').val(price); //set the value
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2y14pzu8/1/)

**Reference**

[.parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

[jQuery - .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)